# bootstrap button and panel

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use bootstrap panel and button in my application. I am also using Jquery. So when I add bootstrap.css in my page I see jquery dialog box and date picker don't display correctly. I think there is css conflict between bootstrap and jquery css. My question is that does jquery css also provide panel and button css ? actually I want to create bootstrap like panel and button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use still twitter bootstrap you can use it as is but remove jquery datepicker css, js and use bootstrap datepicker [here](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/). There will be no conflict then

Comment: thanks, I saw that. It seems that then we would also require changes in javascript code, if we remove jquery css and js and use twitter bootstrap css and js.

Comment: Yes but, if you have not tons of jquery datepicker code, it is not so.  hard. By the way, I mean remove jquery datepicker, not jquery completely, because twitter bootstrap needs jquery :) Remove jquery UI from your project If you would like to use bootstrap template.